# Startup.cs: calling a context of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

My concern is: have a RecurringJon that sends an email on a daily basis. in static email content, it is working fine. but my end-user want that their critical count of items will be sent to them daily. I have a controller for their inventory that compares items to determine which items are at a critical level. but I can't call the _context of the inventory.

I've already tried to add the context in the service but still not working.

**ItemRegContext**

```
namespace Intranet.Controllers
{
   public class ItemRegController : Controller
   {
     private readonly ItemRegContext _context;

     public ItemRegController(ItemRegContext context) 
     {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IRecurringJobManager recurringJob)
{
    app.UseHangfireDashboard();
    recurringJob.AddOrUpdate("", () => SendEmail(), Cron.Minutely());
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}

public void SendEmail()
{

    var message = new MimeMessage();
    var builder = new BodyBuilder();

    string msgFromDB = string.Empty;

    var items = _context.ItemRegs;

    foreach (ItemReg item in items)
    {
        if (item.CritLevel >= item.Qty)
        {
            msgFromDB += "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + item.ItemName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.ItemDesc + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.ManufName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.AsstSerial + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.PartNum + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.TypeName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.CalDate + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.Qty + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.UnitName + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.Remarks + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + item.LocName + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";
        }
        //else {
        //    msgFromDB += "<tr><<td colspan='11'>No critical record on the list</td>></tr>";
        //}
    }
    #region email
    // reference value from appsettings.json
    string host = "smtp.some.com";
    int port = 333;
    bool boole = false;
    string authEmail = "somemail@mail.com";
    string authPass = "somepassword";

    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("somename", "jose.baleros@pttphils.com"));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("somemail@mail.com"));
    message.Subject = "some subjects";
    builder.HtmlBody =
        string.Format(@"
                    <p> Critical Stocks for today " +
                DateTime.Now.ToString() + " </p>" +
            "<table border='1'> " +
            "<thead>" +
            "        <tr> " +
            "            <th> Name </th>" +
            "            <th> Item Description </th>" +
            "            <th> MFR </th>" +
            "            <th> Asset/SN </th>" +
            "            <th> P/N </th>" +
            "            <th> Type </th>" +
            "            <th> CAL Date </th>" +
            "            <th> QTY </th>" +
            "            <th> Unit </th>" +
            "            <th> Remarks </th>" +
            "            <th> Location </th>" +
            "        </tr>" +
            "    </thead>" +
            "    <tbody>" + msgFromDB + "</tbody> " +
            "</table>" +
            "<br />" +
            "<br />");
    message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.Connect(host, port, boole);
        client.Authenticate(authEmail, authPass);
        client.Send(message);
        client.Disconnect(true);
    }

}
```

on the public void `SendEmail()`, `var items = _context.ItemRegs;`
the _context should get the list of ItemRegContext

Comment: Please show us how you are **assigning** to `private readonly ItemRegContext _context;`.

Comment: Please update your question to include that code. A [mcve] would be very useful here.

Comment: what is ItemRegContext here. is it a class , interface or what ? can you please include more code to explain ?

Comment: Is it possible here to put a link from GitHub? if possible I'm going to upload it there and put the link here.

Comment: Are you injecting 'ItemRegContext' to 'ItemRegController' ? this piece of code is not clear, need more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does exactly what I needed.
https://jonhilton.net/simple-background-jobs-with-hangfire-and-aspnet-core/